# Upload image to a parse account

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload, parse-platform

So i'm trying to upload this image in the user class of Parse. First I upload the image from my computer then press submit to send/save it in the image column of the class (which is of the type file):

```
document.write('Profile Picture: ');
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "file");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.write('<br>');

    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = 'Submit';
    button.onclick = function(){
        var user = new Parse.User();
        console.log(x);
        user.set("img", x);      
        user.save(null, {
          success: function(user) {
            alert('New user added!');
          },
          error: function(user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });
    };
    document.body.appendChild(button);
```

I get the following error on the line user.set("img", x); :

Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from

```
'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('file') does not support selection. parse-1.2.19.min.js:1
(anonymous function) parse-1.2.19.min.js:1
w.each.w.forEach parse-1.2.19.min.js:1
t._objectEach.t._each parse-1.2.19.min.js:1
t._decode parse-1.2.19.min.js:1
n.extend.set parse-1.2.19.min.js:2
button.onclick
```

Answer (score 1):

You ought to create a new Parse.File object before you can send a file to the database. To send an image, the following code worked for me.

```
var fileUploadControl = document.getElementById('profile_upload'); //  get a reference to your uploaded file



if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {   //  check if valid input
  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0]; 
  var name = "photo.jpg";     //  save it in your cloud with this name, don't worry, you can have multiple files with same name

  var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);   //  create Parse.File object


}


user.set("img",parseFile);

user.signUp(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    alert("Done!");


  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

I have added a few comments to help you out.

Comment: It takes away the error alright but still doesn't upload the picture in my parse account..no string nothing

Comment: Do you get anything in the console?